# How to load more records on scrolling in tv android box

Tags: android, listview, scroll, android-tv

I have set up setOnScrollListener event on my listview its working good in mobile here is my code

```
movieList.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

                if(scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL){
                    userScrolled = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                if(userScrolled && (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount)){

                    pageNum++;
                    int index = movieList.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                    float indexY = movieList.getScrollY();
                    load_loader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    getMovies();

                    movieList.setSelection(index);
                    userScrolled = false;

                }
            }
        });
```

Now i have installed my app to android tv box my full app is working good in tv box but list view not loading more records i think because of touch scroll tv is not touch its operated by remote navigation please help me to solve this problem thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `listView.setItemsCanFocus(true);` to your ListView so that focusable views inside of your listItems won't be ignored. [Source.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14411124/5832311)

You may also check this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/navigation.html) on how you can actually navigate around your app when using remote control buttons instead of a touch screen.